# innerHTML not working with classname in JS

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

My drop down List to select particular value-

```
<select name="category" id="category" onChange="showDiv(this.value);" >
    <option value="">Select This</option>
    <option value="1">Nokia</option>
    <option value="2">Samsung</option>
    <option value="3">BlackBerry</option>
    </select>
```

This is the div where i want to show the text

> `<span class="catlink"> </span>`

And this is my JS function -

```
    function showDiv( discselect )
    {

    if( discselect === 1)
    {
    alert(discselect); // This is alerting fine
    document.getElementsByClassName("catlink").innerHTML = "aaaaaaqwerty"; // Not working
    }

}
```

Let me know why this is not working, and what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName("catlink")`is selecting **all the elements** in webpage as **array** therefore you have to use **[0]**

```
 function showDiv( discselect ) 
 { 

 if( discselect === 1) 
 { 
 alert(discselect); // This is alerting fine 
 document.getElementsByClassName("catlink")[0].innerHTML = "aaaaaaqwerty"; // Now working 
 } 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code and solution, just one more to add, i need to replace "===" to "==" to make my code working fine. kindly explain it little further the use of [0] as i was totally unaware of this

Comment: [0] will select the first element on the webpage having class catlink

Comment: So now if i have more than span classes named catlink on my page then can i insert text using those [0] , [1] ?? ..wow thats really g8 info :)

Comment: you can also get the total no. of element by document.getElementsByClassName("catlink").length

Comment: Perfect, it works! :) Simple and nice explanation.

Answer (score 4):

You ar creating a `nodeList` (a special array of Nodes) using `getElementsByClassName`. Alternatively you can use `document.querySelector`, which returns the first element with className `.catlink`:

```
function showDiv( discselect ) {
    if( discselect === 1)    {
      document.querySelector(".catlink").innerHTML = "aaaaaaqwerty";
    }
}
```